# Is it possible to add your own bookmarks/tabs to a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, tabs, bookmarks, adobe-reader

I've purchases a few e-books and love it. Some come with a massive list of bookmarks (kewl!) and some not. Regardless, is there a way i can create my OWN bookmarks so i can jump to specific pages? I don't want to mess up the current list of official bookmarks that came with the e-books (where they were provided). It's like i want to add my own sticky note tabs so i can quickly jump between pages etc, without having to remember the page number.

Also, this is for Adobe reader (the free thingy). If it's available in another program (eg. Foxit, please say so also :)  )

cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the Stanza book reader from Lexcycle.  http://www.lexcycle.com/

It allows you to create bookmarks, and plenty of other features for eBooks in many popular formats, including PDF.

It is available free for Windows, Mac, and iPhone.

Comment: So i can add custom bookmarks?

Comment: Yes.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PDF editor, [foxit editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/editor/) works well if you don't mind small watermarks. [OpenOffice](http://openoffice.org) can edit PDFs as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Infix PDF Editor](http://www.pdfediting.com/) gives you full control over adding, deleting and moving bookmarks. It also includes a remarkable 'auto bookmark' feature that creates bookmarks for an entire document automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know [Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/) does support it, so they probably leave it out of the free version to make sure the Pro version is actually worth something. So I can't imagine you can have it in Adobe Reader...

Try one of the programs mentioned in the other answers ;-)